Cannot run multiple ingress controllers on an on-premise Kuberenetes cluster
I am currently creating a SSO service for my ingress with this example(https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/oauth2-proxy.yaml) after I create the oauth2-proxy ingress, I notice that my app ingress(cafe-ingress) has no IP address anymore, how can I fix this issue?
NAME           CLASS   HOSTS                                     ADDRESS                                             PORTS     AGE
cafe-ingress   nginx   becoming-pika-enormously.ngrok-free.app                                                       80, 443   6h2m
oauth2-proxy   nginx   becoming-pika-enormously.ngrok-free.app   172.16.1.145,172.16.2.0,172.16.2.108,172.16.2.109   80, 443   6h29m


My K8s is running with metallb in ARP layer2 mode.

Run this command to see what's the issue: kubectl describe ingress/cafe-ingress

I tried to run describe and logs and everything work fine `Rules:
Host                                     Path  Backends

becoming-pika-enormously.ngrok-free.app
/tea      tea-svc:80 (10.1.77.171:80,10.1.180.204:80,10.1.77.150:80)
/coffee   coffee-svc:80 (10.1.77.177:3000,10.1.180.206:3000,10.1.203.147:3000)`

I just realize that this happen because of the same host, if I change to different host it work but the redirect url after sign in will not work.
